# Trying to activate function in child from sibling, works with only one child so far

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux

So I have a parent component [PC] -> and sibling/child components [SC]

[SC1] displays and clears data using redux actions

[SC2] & [SC3] are dropdown menus that display items that I'm trying to get to clear values from as well. They have their `clearQuery` props that belongs to the 3rd party library I'm using. I can only access `clearQuery` from these components.

Essentially I'm trying to trigger the `clearQuery` action from [SC1] component

After doing some research, I decided to use `this.ref`. It worked on [SC2]! As soon as I did the samething with [SC3] I got the `onRef is not a function` error.

Here's what my code sorta looks like

```
class Parent extends PureComponent {
  clear = () => {
    this.ref.clearValue();
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <SiblingComponent1 clear={this.clear} />
        <SiblingComponent2 onRef={ref => (this.ref = ref)} />
        <SiblingComponent3 onRef={ref => (this.ref = ref)} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

class SiblingComponent2 extends PureComponent {
  componentDidMount() {
    const { onRef } = this.props;
    onRef(this);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    const { onRef } = this.props;
    onRef(null);
  }

  clearValue = () => {
    const { setQuery } = this.props;
    setQuery(null);
  };
}
class SiblingComponent3 extends PureComponent {
  componentDidMount() {
    const { onRef } = this.props;
    onRef(this);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    const { onRef } = this.props;
    onRef(null);
  }

  clearValue = () => {
    const { setQuery } = this.props;
    setQuery(null);
  };
}
```

Maybe I'm not understanding refs correctly.

How do I solve this problem?

Thanks!